# Card Item Alignment - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Okay so I'm trying to align the last two elements in the card so that the first one (button) can be on the left, and another element (Div with multiple social icon images) on the right side. How can I achieve that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap-icons-1.7.2/*">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card col-8 position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">
    <div class="row g-0">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="Logo.png" class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="Logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card-body position-relative">
          <h2 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold;">John Doe</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle pb-3">Developer</h5>
              <p class="card-text pb-3">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <div class="row justify-content-between">
                    <a href="#" class="col-2 btn btn-primary">Portfolio</a>
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <img src="/bootstrap-icons-1.7.2/facebook.svg" alt="Facebook Icon" width="32" height="32">
                        <img src="/bootstrap-icons-1.7.2/instagram.svg" alt="Instagram Icon" width="32" height="32">
                        <img src="/bootstrap-icons-1.7.2/linkedin.svg" alt="Linkedin Icon" width="32" height="32">
                        <img src="/bootstrap-icons-1.7.2/twitter.svg" alt="Twitter Icon" width="32" height="32">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to get. When I ran your snippet code I saw button on the left and icons on the right.

Comment: @Movs This is how I see it: http://prntscr.com/26d895r

Comment: don't create a new question for a minor edit to the previous one, edit the previous one instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is will work for your `images` also, but I imported `font-awesome` icons for your social media, as your images were not rendering. Essentially, all I added was a div `col-4` for your `a tag` and used `col-8` for your social media icons. Then I used `text-end` on your social icons to align them to the right. I also added `align-items-center` so they are in line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap-icons-1.7.2/*">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card col-8">
    <div class="row g-0">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="Logo.png" class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="Logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card-body position-relative">
          <h2 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold;">John Doe</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle pb-3">Developer</h5>
              <p class="card-text pb-3">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <div class="col-4">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Portfolio</a>
                  </div>
                    <div class="col-8 text-end">
                        <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```